How to use Redis as a cache in an Spring MVC Application
I am using Spring MVC Architecture with Spring transaction and Hibernate ORM as my databases services.
Now I want to use redis as my second level cache for hibernate.
I tried using @EnableCacheing and @Cacheable on enties with creation of CacheManager Bean
I also tried RedisConnectionFactory but I couldn'd find any method to create Clusters and Masters and Slaves
